# Getting nullpointer exception in jmeter logs

Tags: java, jmeter

I am trying to write values of jmeter variables into a file using BSF post processor, but am getting an error if I call a variable which has no value

```
temp6 = vars.get("host_2_g1");  
out.write(temp6);
```

Following is the message I am seeing  in the jmeter log file

```
2015/11/08 21:47:29 WARN  - jmeter.extractor.BSFPostProcessor: Problem in BSF script org.apache.bsf.BSFException: BeanShell script error: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: // VALUES is the Reference Name in regex ext . . . '' : vars .get ( "host_2_g1" )
```

BSF info: [script] at line: 0 column: columnNo

I already know that there is no variable being returned by the name "host_2_g1", how can i handle it so that at-least my code works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your script:

1. `out` should be uppercase: `OUT`
2. `OUT` is a shorthand for [PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html). It won't write strings, is expects byte array, so you need to convert your `host_2_g1` variable to byte array via [getBytes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()) method
3. If your `host_2_g1` variable may be not set - it's better to add explicit check.

Modified code:

```
temp6 = vars.get("host_2_g1");

if (temp6 != null) {
    OUT.write(temp6.getBytes());
}
else {
    OUT.write("host_2_g1 is null".getBytes());
}
```

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter.